# to remove duplicates from data type (long strings , list ,a dictionary, tuples)

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, tuples

```
def remove_duplicate(string):
        new = ""
        for i in string:
            if i not in new and string.count(i) >= 1:
                new += i
        return new
```

---

```
sample input "AAAAABBBBSSSSS"
sample output "ABS"
sample input [1,2,4,3,2,2,2]
sample output [1,2,4,3]
sample input {"hello": 3, "hi": 1 , "bye" : 2}
sample output {"hello": 1, "hi": 1 , "bye" : 1}
sample input (1,2,3,3,4,4)
sample output (1,2,3,4)
```

only able to solve for string and lists, above code only works for strings
not able to solve for dictionaries and all data types together

Comment: try looking what sets are as they are optimized for finding duplicates. so you can add datatype items to a set and then use set functions to find duplicates. for dictionaries to find both key and value use `dictionary_name.items()`

Comment: ok thanks let me check is there a way to find whether our input given will be which one of data type

Comment: can someone please tell me me why i am getting negative votes this platform is for helping each other right. i dont know how to answer this then what else should i have asked

Comment: calm down! you should read how to ask so that you know how to ask. about the question above idk maybe by using `try except` statements and trying to do action with data and if an error occurs go and check the next option for example try to `.append()` to data and make an exception when it cannot do it because it is dictionary for example and so on

Comment: ok thanks sir what i did is first checked whether the input is which among these and a made a function for each of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what you want, the other answer is not useful about strings and dicts, also conversion to main type is skipped:

```
def remove_duplicates(input_argument):
    input_type = type(input_argument)
    if input_type is str:
        result = ''
        for character in input_argument:
            if character not in result:
                result += character
    elif input_type is dict:
        result = {}
        for key in input_argument:
            result[key] = 1  # or any other value you want
    else:
        result = input_type(set(input_argument))
    return result
```

Now your examples:

```
remove_duplicates("AAAAABBBBSSSSS")
  # "ABS"
remove_duplicates([1,2,4,3,2,2,2])
  # [1,2,4,3]
remove_duplicates({"hello": 3, "hi": 1 , "bye" : 2})
  # {"hello": 1, "hi": 1 , "bye" : 1}
remove_duplicates((1,2,3,3,4,4))
  # (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: ya its great its a bit simplified to what i did was i just made 4 functions for 4 types and checked for the input its better sir . thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` to achieve the same , then convert back to the kind/type of output you want. 
Something like .

```
def remove_duplicate(input_parameter):
    unique =set(input_parameter)
    # Do the type conversion or format 
    # of output you want 
    
    return unique
```

It will work for all other type but for dictionary .  For dictionary it is not clear what you want to acheive.

Comment: ok thanks sorry i am not able to correct your answer i dont have enough reputation output of the dictionary must only have one value for each key

Comment: @NELSONJOSEPH , a key can't be duplicate in dictionary .

Comment: @NELSONJOSEPH , do you want to assign value of each key to 1 ?